# Why is my Do While loop returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning javascript and I'm a little confused on why my do-while loop isn't working. Maybe I'm missing a core concept of how it's supposed to work, but I just don't seem to get why this isn't working. I could use a for loop or regular while loop to iterate through this list, and I understand those fine, but I'd like to figure it out using a do-while loop. Can anyone explain what is wrong?

```
i=0

var names = ['Bobby', 'Chris', 'John', 'Joe'];


do{
   i+=1
}
while(i < 4){
 console.log(names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax should be with everything between the `do` and `while` braces:

```
do{
   console.log(names[i]);
   i+=1
} while(i < 4);
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUMN9/))

Comment: Ah, thank you for your help. I guess I was confused by Code Academy's explanation.

Comment: I'm actually fascinated by the fact that it doesn't just break and logs undefined and then returns an undefined value. Can you do/while/do/while? That would be really stupid but awesome JS trivia.

Comment: lol. It doesn't throw any errors. It just evaluates the last block one final time and returns the last statement evaluated even if you try to change the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, when you're using `do{ }while()` the while part doesn't take any braces, there's no need to.

Think of `Do..while blocks` as "Shoot first, ask later"

In other words, you execute a block of code first, and then you figure out if the condition is still true.

The reason you're getting an undefined output is because you're trying to access an undefined element.

JavaScript arrays are zero based, it means that if you have an array with **4 elements** you're going to have indices going from **0 to 3**

Because of the nature of `do{ } while()` you're incrementing your `i` **BEFORE** testing whether or not you've reached the end of the array, therefore when your loop ends, your `i` has the value of `4`

and you're asking javascript for the value of names[4] which doesn't exist, and you end up with an `undefined` console output.

How to fix this?

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Your code seems to me like you're trying to access the last element on your array, if that's what you're trying to do change your current condition form:

`while(i < 4)` to `while(i < 3)` and your code will work

Don't take my word for it, here's a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8exp/